# Why does a modal view controller disappear after switching apps?

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

I am displaying a modal view controller in my app. When I switch to a different app and then back to mine, the modal view controller is no longer displayed, what I see instead is the view behind it.

I know that the modal view controller is still in the view hierarchy and is simply not drawn, because I can call `dismissModalViewController` on the parent view controller and the app will behave correctly (if I don't call `dismissModalViewController`, displaying another modal view controller puts the app into a weird state).

Has anyone else encountered this? What can be done to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening there, but please don't use MVC abbreviation for modal view controller, as it's used for [model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller) pattern. It sounds similar, but is not.

Comment: Does you modal vc call `viewDidUnload` or `dealloc` method?

Comment: you should provide the code, otherwise it is guesswork. Application and VC lifecycle events implementation and all the code where you present and dismiss View Controllers. And the VC in question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing you should try: try using some "well known" View Controller instead of the one you display and see if you get the same result with disappearance. Like UIImagePickerViewController